# How do I prevent IntelliJ IDEA from adding 'additional info' to a patch?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, patch

When I create a patch with IntelliJ IDEA the following lines are inserted before each file in the patch:

```
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
```

Is there any way that I can prevent IntelliJ from adding these lines?  I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13 Community Edition.

Additional info: it's a Java project, using Subversion as the VCS, my default file settings and project file settings are both UTF-8.  Patch created with 'VCS -> Create Patch...'.